# What is the story of the Shady Records?

Tags: record-labels, backstory

Eminem, Slaughterhouse, 50 Cent and many more awesome rappers and music producers belong to the [Shady Records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shady_Records).

> [image: Shady Records]

Since I’m a huge 'Shady' fan, can anyone tell me the tale of Shady Records?

Comment: I propose to close this question, since the user apparently doesn't have an exact question and expects a long story. Quoting his comment to the answer given: "I was expecting a story that says stuff like 'how' it was started by the artists. How it started many artists and other things."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Shady Records website](http://shadyrecords.com/about/)

> Shady Records is an American record label specializing in hip hop music. Eminem and his manager Paul Rosenberg founded the label in 1999 after the highly successful release of The Slim Shady LP.
>   Since the formation, the label has signed nine acts. It has also been part of the business venture in Shade 45 radio station via Sirius Satellite Radio, and had its own dedicated special edition magazine via XXL magazine. The label has also seen positive times when being part of the successful international Anger Management tours and, in 2006, released an album showcasing its then roster on Eminem Presents: The Re-Up. It was also the label to be contracted for putting together the soundtrack to the Eminem-starring film, 8 Mile, which had the lead single “Lose Yourself.” The song went on to take the first ever Academy Award for Best Original Song given to a song in the hip hop genre.
>   The labels acts over the years have earned RIAA certifications of platinum or higher on seven of its 14 released albums. Signed acts include D12, Slaughterhouse, Yelawolf, Bad Meets Evil and Joell Ortiz, while former acts include Obie Trice, Stat Quo, Bobby Creekwater and Cashis.

Even more information can be found on the [Shady Records Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shady_Records)